# Existe alguma parte da moderação do site referente a ética (não sei se seria a melhor forma de expressão)?

Tags: debate, perguntas

A parte de decisões da moderação é voltada ao meio técnico e profissional / regras do site (maioria assim o faz) ou tem no meio opiniões pessoais (vi mais de um usuário assim agir) como influencia para a tomada de decisões?

Pergunto isso pois faço poucas perguntas e respostas, e estou tentando (desanimado ao ver "certas coisas") migrar do fórum que contribuo atualmente para o Stack e hoje ao responder uma questão me veio a mensagem de que contribuo pouco positivamente e por isso não posso mais responder, e ao ver a centrar de ajudar me deparo com isso: "O único jeito de encerrar um bloqueio de publicação é contribuir positivamente com o site".

O que está acontecendo afinal? pois tenho duas respostas e uma pergunta, e ao meu ver, boas contribuições (me corrijam caso esteja enganado).

Com o contribuir se não é possível responder às questões?

Comment: É muito estranho isso.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O que ocorreu com você não foi ação de nenhum usuário ou moderador, e sim um bloqueio automático imposto pelo sistema. Não se sabe exatamente o algoritmo que determina esse bloqueio (eles não divulgam para dificultar que se tente burlar), mas no seu caso deve ter relação com as respostas excluídas.

Você postou cinco respostas no total, sendo 3 excluídas:

1. [Esta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/60314/include-require-dentro-de-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-m%C3%A9todos/60329#60329) você mesmo excluiu.
2. [Esta outra](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/60729/quais-seriam-as-pr%C3%A1ticas-recomendadas-para-commits-no-git/61381#61381) foi convertida em comentário por um moderador.
3. [Esta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51285/requisi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-jquery-post-php-mysql-n%C3%A3o-grava-os-dados/60401#60401) era um pedido de esclarecimento, que você mesmo excluiu.

Eu acho que o sistema foi muito severo com você. Duas das três respostas excluídas deviam mesmo ser comentários, mas postá-las como respostas é um erro extremamente comum em novos usuários, especialmente enquanto não têm reputação suficiente para comentar em qualquer publicação.

Assim como as regras que determinam o bloqueio não são conhecidas, as que determinam seu cancelamento também não são. Mas talvez baste desfazer a exclusão de uma delas para resolver o problema. A melhor candidata é [a resposta sobre os `require`s  em PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/60314/include-require-dentro-de-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-m%C3%A9todos/60329#60329). Experimente desfazer a exclusão. Recomendo ainda editar o que você escreveu para tentar responder ao que foi perguntado, já que a resposta acabou fugindo da pergunta.

---

**UPDATE** Não precisou nem desfazer a exclusão de nada, bastou receber uns votos positivos nas outras respostas que o bloqueio já foi suspenso pelo sistema :)

Comment: Agradeço pela sua atenção. Esta em especial o autor além de não dar uma especificação inicial, ainda me "esnobou" em outro ponto (aonde me senti desrespeitado), dando origem à discussão, onde exclui por não achar edificante ao site, mas vou fazer esta tentativa.

Comment: @anderson Além do que o bfavaretto falou, a melhor maneira de sair do bloqueio automático é editando seus posts no site para melhorar a qualidade. Se acontecer algo assim de novo, tente reler suas respostas e melhorar o máximo possível, aumentando a qualidade e, assim, "contribuindo positivamente com o site"

Comment: Sim, sempre busco fazer desta forma, mas obrigado mesmo assim.